# Animate many objects each object has many animations

Tags: animation

I'm working on an FPS game and I have many weapons to animate. Each weapon has many animations such as idle, walk, shoot, reload ... etc. Some weapons have very similar animations.

I am a beginner in blender so I don't know how to create each animation for each weapon.

Is there a way to make it easier because it's too hard and boring to create animations for each weapon.

I'm asking this question because I believe you have good workflows for this kind of work rather than the hard way that I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Hi, please make a simple example of what you're trying to do... is not so clear...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Modular Rig that can support all your weapons, this has trade-offs for example, you will have to make all weapons work the same way, you cannot rig a knife and expect it to work the same way like a rifle, but you can rig a pistol using a rifle rig, that's for a simple rig. But, if your rig is good enough, then it can adapt to some extent anything you throw at it, but that usually will require a average amount of knowledge in constraints and rigging.

That being said, if you are a beginner in blender, this is an advanced project and I am afraid you will not find a easy solution. I can point you to a great rigging tutorial with great techniques, but it's not for beginners, so keep that in mind. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqiA9E9dHnk

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for replay, that's mean I must do each animation for each weapon the problem is not all weapons has same dimensions so I need to adjust arms with every weapon before start animate although all weapons have same walk, shot ... etc animations same move but not have same dimensions